# Terminus für unzulässige Satzverkürzung

Tags: sentence-structure

Ich bin auf einem Fragebogen über folgenden Satz gestolpert, bei dem, m. E. unzulässigerweise, ein Teil der Wörter nicht wiederholt, sondern weggekürzt wurde.

Im Spaß ist dieses Verfahren von Heinz Erhard in zugespitzter Weise verwendet worden. Hier der nicht so komische Satz:

> Wurden Sie über die Folgen des Übergewichts aufgeklärt und Vorschläge
>   zu Diäten gemacht?

Es klingt für mich sofort holprig, aber auf den ersten Blick scheint hier nur ein "wurden" unterschlagen, das vorne im Satz schon steht.

Aber das 'wurden' steht in zwei unterschiedlichen (... Konstellationen?). Einmal als *Wurden Sie*, einmal als *wurden Ihnen*. Man merkt wie es kracht, wenn man das persönliche *Du* verwendet:

> Wurdest Du über die Folgen des Übergewichts aufgeklärt und wurden (Dir) Vorschläge
>   zu Diäten gemacht?

Gibt es einen Fachterminus für die zulässige Auslassung

> Wurdest Du über die Folgen des Übergewichts und den Mangel an Sport aufgeklärt?

sowie die unzulässige Auslassung?

Hilfsweise sind auch gut begründete Widersprüche gegen meine Aussage, die Auslassung sei hier unzulässig, willkommen.

Und hier die absichtliche Form, die aber leicht anders funktioniert:

> Ich heiße Heinz Erhardt und Sie herzlich willkommen.

... insofern, als es mit der Doppeldeutigkeit eines Wortes arbeitet was bei *wurden* so nicht der Fall ist.

Comment: Bzgl. Konstellation: *unterschiedliche grammatische Zusammenhänge*, wie es in dem Wiki-Link zu Syllepse heißt (siehe meine antwort), trifft es imho am besten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fangen wir mit dem einfachen Teil an, der zulässigen Auslassung:

Grundsätzlich handelt es sich ja schon mal um eine [Ellipse](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_%28Sprache%29). Ich denke, der Teil ist dir sicherlich bekannt. Hier handelt es sich aber ganz konkret um ein [Zeugma](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma_%28Sprache%29). Es handelt sich also um eine rhetorische Figur, wobei das Verb eben eingespart wird.

Auf der Wiki-Seite findest du auch dein Heinz-Erhardt-Beispiel:

> „Ich heiße nicht nur Heinz Erhardt, sondern Sie auch herzlich willkommen.“

Ein Überbegriff, der neben Zeugma auch die [Apokoinu](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokoinu) beinhaltet, ist [Brachylogie](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachylogie). Damit habe ich jetzt, glaube ich, alle wichtigen Begriffe, die diese Art der Auslassung betreffen, genannt.

Auf der Wiki-Seite von Zeugma stößt man aber auf einen weiteren interessanten Begriff: [Syllepse](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse). Dort heißt es:

> Ein einmalig verwendeter Satzteil (Subjekt, Objekt o. ä.) oder eine grammatische Form bzw. Funktion wird in der Syllepse mehrfach in unterschiedlichem Sinne ergänzt, so dass er auch unterschiedliche grammatische Zusammenhänge in Bezug auf Person, Kasus und Genus erzeugt.

Weiter heißt es:

> Im Gegensatz zum Zeugma (in jüngerer Terminologie) ist hier eine semantische Unschärfe nicht beabsichtigt, sondern nur eine syntaktische Verkürzung.

Und das erste Beispiel passt wie die Faust aufs Auge:

> Ihr sucht euren Vorteil, wir unseren.

Wie in deinem Beispiel oben, ist hier der ausgelassene (redundante) Teil nicht exakt übereinstimmend, sondern nur ähnlich. Vollständig heißt es ja:

> Ihr sucht euren Vorteil, wir **suchen** unseren **Vorteil**.

Syllepse - wenn ich den Begriff also richtig verstehe - bedeutet also, dass durch die Auslassung nur die Syntax vereinfacht/gekürzt wurde und unter Umständen die Semantik darunter leidet. Sprich: *Unzulässige* Kürzungen sind inbegriffen.

In deinem Beispiel würde ich übrigens nicht sagen, dass nur das Verb ausgelassen wurde, sondern der entscheidende Faktor ist das Personalpronomen. Die Problematik ist ja, dass es sich um einen anderen Fall handelt. *Sie* ist Nominativ, während *Ihnen* Dativ ist.

> **Wurden Sie** über die Folgen des Übergewichts aufgeklärt und **wurden Ihnen** Vorschläge zu Diäten gemacht?

Comment: Ellipse habe ich schon gehört, aber wieder vergessen. Ich denke da erst an viele Argumente in Funktionsaufrufen `def main (args: String*)`, was aber wohl auch von `Auslassung kommt`, dann an Rotationsfiguren.

Comment: Ok, weiß nicht welche Sprache das jetzt sein soll, aber die Main-Funktion ist zumindest in Java, C# und C(++) keine Ellipse. Klassisches Beispiel für eine Ellipse sind printf (C) oder String.Format (C#).

Comment: `echo 'class E {public static void main (String... args){System.out.println ("doch! War übrigens Scala.");}}'  > E.java && javac E.java && java E`

Comment: Die `main`-Methode in Java kann man als `public static void main(String... args)` schreiben, muss man aber nicht. Scala wäre `def main(args:Array[String])`, also hier keine Ellipse.

Comment: @Landei: a) Hat auch m.W. niemand behauptet, dass man bei Java eine Ellipse nutzen **muss**. b) kann man in Scala sehr wohl `object Sample extends App {
  def main (args: String*) = println ("Sample")
}` eine Ellipse benutzen - es ist hier nur nicht **die** main-Methode, sondern **eine** (andere) main-Methode, die nicht die übliche überschreibt. Es kompiliert aber problemlos u. lässt sich auch unkompliziert benutzen.

Comment: Na ja, "main-Methode" ist ein feststehender Begriff in C-ähnlichen Sprachen. "Ellipse" ist meiner Meinung nach für das programmiersprachliche Konzept sowieso ein unglücklicher Ausdruck, weil es sich eigentlich nur auf das typographische `...` bezieht. Insofern wäre es eindeutiger, von "Varargs" oder "variadischen Funktionen" zu sprechen.

Comment: Ey, jetzt nicht meine Antwort dazu missbrauchen, um über Programmiertechniken zu diskutieren ;p

Comment: +1 schöne Antwort... ich denke jedoch nicht, dass das Personalpronomen hier eine große Rolle spielt. "Es wurden Vorschläge gemacht..." ist ein legitimer Satz der sich so auch in der Zeitung finden könnte. Daher ist das "Ihnen" hier keinesfalls zwingend.
Die Holprigkeit entsteht meiner Meinung nach nur dadurch dass das Subjekt den Numerus wechselt. Erst Einzahl - dann Mehrzahl. Das erste "wurden" ist im Kopf ein Verb in Einzahl und kann eigentlich nicht für Mehrzahl verwendet werden. Sagt man wurden erneut, ist der Satz ok.

Comment: @Emanuel Ja, ist richtig. Man kann ein Personalpronomen natürlich problemlos auslassen, aber das geht z.b. nicht in dem Satz *Ihr sucht euren Vorteil, wir suchen unseren Vorteil.* Solange aus dem Kontext erkennbar ist, um wen es sich handelt, bzw. wer hier angesprochen wird, ja, lässt man es einfach weg.